# Tensorflow neural network predicts different values after restoring

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have trained a neural network using TensorFlow 1.8.0 and eager execution. After training I saved it and there were no problems with loading and predicting when I did that just in cmd. Then I made a python server (using flask) which loads the trained model to receive POST requests with data in format json, which is later standardized and proceeded to the model. But then every time I restarted the server the neural network gave different answers with different probabilities.
Some weights were randomly initialized somehow but the problem is that when I wasn't using a server, everything acts as it has to.

I was suggested to use:

```
tf.set_random_seed(1234)
```

It did help with the random answers but the predictions from the network were different from the ones I got when trained it. I changed the integers in the tf.set_random_seed and had different results every time, so I suppose that I just need to give the right argument to tf.set_random_seed and the network will perform as I have trained it.

So how should I know what exactly to write in tf.set_random_seed or does it work completely different from the way I understood? Or is there a problem with something else?

The code looks like this:

```
imports
tf.enable_eager_execution()

tf.set_random_seed(5)
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
...
])
optimizer
root = tfe.Checkpoint(optimizer=optimizer, model=model, 
optimizer_step=tf.train.get_or_create_global_step())    
root.restore(tf.train.latest_checkpoint(checkpoint_directory))

@app.route('/calc', methods=['POST'])
def predict_data():
    read and parse json
    class_ids = ["false", "true"]
    predict_data = tf.convert_to_tensor([data_to_predict])
    predictions = model(predict_data)
    for i, logits in enumerate(predictions):
        class_idx = tf.argmax(logits).numpy()
        p = tf.nn.softmax(logits)[class_idx]
        name = class_ids[class_idx]
        return("{\"Result\":"+ name+",\"Probability\":"+str(float(p))+"}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
app.run(debug, port)
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Protocol Buffers](https://www.tensorflow.org/extend/tool_developers/) for tensorflow.

Also make your tensorflow training and Eager Execution binded with tf.Session() , which will make the already stored model's graph stored in the Session class.